# Java-JFXpanel refresh page cause JVM　crash -- Threading issue

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I try to embed a JavaFX panel to java Swing using the tutorial from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm)

I am using java 8 update 20, JavaFX 2.0 or 2.2 (not very sure how to check)

Here is my code:

JavaFX code:

```
public class SwingFXWebView{  

    public final JFXPanel jfxpanel;

    public SwingFXWebView(String[] para, int width, int height){  
        jfxpanel = new JFXPanel();
        jfxpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //add(jfxpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Platform.runLater( new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                initFX(jfxpanel);
            }
        });
    }


    private static void initFX(JFXPanel jfxpanel){
        Scene scene = createScene();
        jfxpanel.setScene(scene);
    }


    private static Scene createScene() {
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        Group  root  =  new  Group();
        final Scene  scene  =  new  Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE);
        WebView browser;

        browser = new WebView();
     //browser.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
        browser.autosize();
        WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
        webEngine.load("www.google.ca");

        root.getChildren().add(browser); 
        return (scene);
   }
```

Swing code:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {  
    //Jdesktop browser
        sfwv = new SwingFXWebView(para, panelContents.getWidth(),panelContents.getHeight());
        panelContents.add(sfwv.jfxpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

....
}
```

It works so far. if I mouse right click to refresh the page and do it for second time, the JVM crashes.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005c2728e0, pid=5376, tid=5084
#
```

It looks like the thread problem, but I strictly follow the tutorial from oracle. Any idea what I have done wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you on java 8? You can use 1 thread for JavaFx and Swing for the events.

Comment: @keuleJ Yes, I am using java8update20, is it necessary to switch to java 7. The tutorial says it is better the keep javafx and swing separated thread.

Comment: You could try out the experimental -Djavafx.embed.singleThread=true
so that JavaFx and Swing share that JavaFx uses the EDT as application thread

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212042/javafx-jfxpanel-bug
I have posted the solution here.