# JavaFX-JFXpanel bug?

Tags: java, javafx

```
public class JavaApplication3 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */


public void initAndShowGUI() {
    // This method is invoked on the EDT thread
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing and JavaFX");
    final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    frame.add(fxPanel);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            initFX(fxPanel);
        }
   });
}

private  void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
    // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
    Scene scene = createScene();
    fxPanel.setScene(scene);
}

private  Scene createScene() {
    Group  root  =  new  Group();
    Scene  scene  =  new  Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE);
       WebView browser;

     browser = new WebView();
     //browser.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
     browser.autosize();
     WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
     String Qlink = "https://www.google.ca";
     webEngine.load(Qlink);

     root.getChildren().add(browser); 
     return (scene);

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","10.10.6.61");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","6666");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost","10.10.6.61");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","6666");
            JavaApplication3 j = new JavaApplication3();
            j.initAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
} 
}
```

Here is the program that is 90% as same as the oracle's sample code.
Either I refresh the page twice or wait a bit-longer, JVM crashes itself.
What am I doing wrong so that the outcome is such? Please point out.
It is easy to reproduce. I am using java7u22, jfxrt is the jre default included.
your help much appreciated!

Edit:
I will post the error showing on the IDE which is very long. I will also provide the core dump log file if you ask. Sorry for the grammar which probably make you hard to understand me.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005c2728e3, pid=812, tid=5280
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64     compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [glass.dll+0x128e3]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: C:\Users\robin.ASIGRA\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\hs_err_pid812.mdmp
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\robin.ASIGRA\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\hs_err_pid812.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

**Update on 06/13-14**

My OS is window server R2 2008 and java version is 7
I did try to update java version to 8 and the problem remained.
This app must be built in java7 environment.
I found it is a [bug](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23456) of java7  on windows server R2 2008 and there is an solution for this.

> This issue occurs on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and Java 7u45 (JavaFX 2.2.45). I've solved it enabling Desktop Experience feature (on the remote server, go to Administrative Tools --> Server Manager). Pay attention to the fact that this feature enables also Windows Defender service and Microsoft doc doesn't report it.

After I have done this, the problem was solved.

Comment: First of all, it's not Java, it's you. Second, please post the stack trace, and MCVE, and the specific error. Finally, fix your grammar and formatting.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Sir, I have done the things you ask. Please feel free to ask questions and I can email you the core dump log. You probably want to test my code your own environment. If everything works fine, please let me know.

Comment: Does it behave the same way if you upgrade to a more recent JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*

As noted by the original poster in his question update, this issue was specific to the use of an older version of Java on a Windows R2 2008 server, which was addressed in Java 8 as part of [RT-23456 Java crashes on Windows 2008 R2 trying to run Java FX demo 'Ensemble'](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23456).

*Works for me*

I ran your application on Win 7, Java 8u20b11 (with the proxy setup commented out) and it worked for me.

You can download a [Java 8 development release](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) to get a Java version which fixes the issue.  If you must stick with Java 7 (not really recommended), then you can apply a workaround as noted in the question update.

Comment: You first guess mostly correct, therefore, I will rate you as correct answer while there is no other answer. Thanks, bro.